# Update to emacs 26 broken my orgmode habits

Tags: org-mode, org-habit

Every time that I mark my habits as DONE I got this error in `*Messages*` buffer:

```
TODO state changed to DONE
TODO state changed to NEXT
setq: Invalid time zone specification: (nil nil nil)
Note stored
```

I already searched for this error and can't get any clue how to avoid it.

This is the stacktrace of the error: https://pastebin.com/0vLm45P0

This error only occurs with emacs 26.1, when I tried with emacs 25.3 it works well.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal config which reproduces this issue?

Comment: What OS are you running Emacs on? There's a similar bug in Org mode caused by changes in Emacs' date handling code, so maybe that's what's happening to you.

Comment: I'm running Emacs on Ubuntu 16.04 @metaturso

Comment: @phils I have a confusing orgmode configuration, but my config works well in Emacs 25, so I don't think that is the cause of the bug... you can see my setup on github.com/squiter/emacs-dotfiles

Comment: This seems to be data related: you have some timestamp in a file, `org-timestamp-change` is called, it gets the timestamp, parses it using `org-parse-timestring` and end up with a time spec like this: `(0 0 0 12 8 2018 (nil nil nil))` which is indeed illegal, so `encode-time` barfs on it. But I didn't find enough information in the backtrace to figure out what timestamp it was looking at. One simple thing that you can try if you don't have too many timestamps is to evaluate `(org-timestamp-change 1 'day)` on each timestamp and find out if it barfs on one of them or maybe all of them. Maybe ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixes when I upgraded my orgmode to lastast version: 9.1.13